# Elasticsearch. Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]

Tags: python, elasticsearch, connection

After writing this code I get a connection error.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
doc = {'author': 'kimchy','text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.'}
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
```

Is the problem in the code or in my computer?
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Is elasticsearch running on your local machine?

Answer (score 1):

CURL: localhost:9200 to check if the elastic search is running on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. 
The problem was that the elasticsearch server was not running when I run the code.